# rxjava transformation operation (flatmap usage)

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, transformation, flatmap

I have this task to implement with rxJava, but I'm new to reactive programming and not sure if I'm implementing it with best practice or even if I'm understanding and doing it correctly. So please give me advice and comments thanks in advance!

**Task statement:**
Basically what I need to accomplish is to fetch from database a list of ObjectA, then convert this list of ObjectA to a list of ObjectB, then convert this list of ObjectB to SearchResultOfObjectB object.

list of A -> list of B -> search result of B (a single object that has list of B as an attribute)

**My thought process:**

- Fetch from the database a list of ObjectA, and store it as Single<List>
- Convert Single<List> of ObjectA to Single<List> of ObjectB
- Convert Single<List> of ObjectB to Single of SearchResultOfObjectB

**My implementation:**

```
final Single<List<ObjectA>> singleOfObjectAList = fetchFromDatabase(); // one time DB request
final Single<SearchResultOfObjectB> result = singleOfObjectAList.flatMap(list -> Observable.from(list)
                .map(AToBMapper::mapAToB)
                .toList()
                .map(BToSearchResultMapper::mapBToSearchResult)
                .toSingle());
```

My current implementation is working fine, but still wanted to see if this is the correct way to do it for this task.

Comment: It is okay. You can simplify the `flatMap` to `flattenAsObservable(list -> list)` though.

Comment: @kaicheng-hu You must to know that if you use `Single` type to get data from database and there is no such record in it, you will get an exception. You must use `Single` only if you absolutely confident that there is one record in database at least. Otherwise you must to use `Maybe`

Answer (score 0):

I think the code is already correct, but I would make some slight changes to make it a little simpler.

```java
final Single<SearchResultOfObjectB> result = singleOfObjectAList.flatMapPublisher(Flowable::fromIterable)
        .map(AToBMapper::mapAToB)
        .toList()
        .map(BToSearchResultMapper::mapBToSearchResult);
```